# How to turn date values in a column into multiple columns of dates

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to unpivot this table using T-SQL in SSMS. I don't need to aggregate anything and I am not able to predict the update dates for each ticket. I am using `row_number() over partition by` to force the sort in the first table and I need to maintain the horizontal sort of dates by ticket in the desired table.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Change this table:

| rownum | ticket | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1/1/2022 |
| 2 | 1 | 1/3/2022 |
| 1 | 2 | 1/27/2022 |
| 1 | 3 | 3/1/2022 |
| 2 | 3 | 4/2/2022 |
| 3 | 3 | 3/1/2022 |
| 1 | 4 | 7/11/2022 |

to this table:

| ticket | Dt1 | Dt2 | Dt3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 1/3/2022 |  |
| 2 | 1/27/2022 |  |  |
| 3 | 3/1/2022 | 4/2/2022 | 5/3/2022 |
| 4 | 7/11/2022 |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ticket,
       [dt1],
       [dt2],
       [dt3]
FROM   (SELECT ticket,
               Concat('DT', rownum) AS Col,
               updated
        FROM   TEST) Src
       PIVOT ( Max(updated)
             FOR col IN ( [DT1],
                          [DT2],
                          [DT3] ) ) Pvt
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=632e03aad0cf5794f02a595229b628c8)